# Install php SQLSRV for php5.6-fpm on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to install sqlsrv and pdo extensions compatible with PHP5.6-fpm on Ubuntu 20.04 for an old Project I am working on that connects with MS-SQL server.
I can't install it from the official repo.

I had tried to use this:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

But it says it require higher PHP version.
Is there anyway to install it from other source?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you have a lot of conlicting version requirements to deal with here. sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv v3.2 was released with PHP 5.6 support. sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv v4.0 was released with Ubuntu 15.04 and 16.04 support. sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv v5.9 was released with Ubuntu 20.04 support, but dropped support for PHP 7.2 (and presumably earlier). I'd be exploring a VirtualBox environment running something Ubuntu before 15.04 to host your dependencies. REF: [Release Notes for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/release-notes-php-sql-driver)

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an older project...did you manage to make it work?